# Is there a way to reset the error badges in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

Netbeans sometimes displays error badges in situations where no actual error occours. (Often on folders, too)

Although Google finds many pages reporting this issue for various Netbeans versions, I could not found a solution to reset the error badges without deleting and re-creating the project with a different name (!).

How can I remove the badges besides recreating the project?

Somewhere Netbeans has to store the information which folder has an error badge. Perhaps it is possible to delete some kind of cache and be done with it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I discovered it myself: The Netbeans errors are cached in the `index` sub-directory of [the Netbeans user directory](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir). Here are the some .err and .warn files, which contain the error and the warning messages.

That's also the reason why recreating a project with the same name doesn't get rid of the badges: The data is stored outside of the project.

Deleting all *.err and *.warn files in that directory and all sub directories makes Netbeans forget the error badges until they are recreated because of a real compile error.

PS: Be prepared for a rescan of your projects after deleting files from the cache, but it should be quick if no other files have been deleted.

Comment: my var/cache/index has directories that go from s1 to s1380 (with what appears to be every number in between). Can I just nuke the whole directory?

Comment: OK, for the record: Shutdown NetBeans, and then delete var/cache and restart (moving it to cache.old works too).

Answer (score 3):

**NetBeans has moved the userdir directory**

See here for your specific OS: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir

Unix-Like Systems (and Mac OS for NB 7.1 and earlier) script:

```
find ~/.netbeans/7.1/var/cache/index/ -name "*.err" -exec rm  {} \;
find ~/.netbeans/7.1/var/cache/index/ -name "*.warn" -exec rm  {} \;
```

Mac OS Systems NB 7.2 and later script:

```
find ~/Library/Caches/NetBeans/7.2rc1/index/ -name "*.err" -exec rm {} \;
find ~/Library/Caches/NetBeans/7.2rc1/index/ -name "*.warn" -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can download the netbeans's cache eraser plugin: 
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40014/cache-eraser

You have to configure the cache dir path, it appears in netbeans about screen.

Erase the cache with the plugin and the errors disappear.

Answer (score 2):

After 4 years with this annoying red errors badges, i decided to make something on my own as windows user (you can do something alike for others OS) to get rid of this.
You have to create a batch script as follow :

```
:: DEFINE YOUR NETBEANS APP PATH HERE
set cache_path=C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\
set exe_path=C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\bin\netbeans64.exe


:: SEARCH FOR .ERR FILES WITHIN CACHE PATH AND DELETE THEM
del /s /q /f %cache_path%*.err

:: OPEN NETBEANS APP AFTER .ERR CLEANING IS DONE
start "" "%exe_path%"

:: CLOSE CONSOLE
exit 0
```

You have to modify the two first var line to change for you own Netbeans paths.
Save this code in a bat file ("run_clean_netbeans.bat" for exemple) and run it.
The script will look for all .err files in the cache directory of netbeans, delete them, and run the Netbeans app just after.
Error badges won't show up anymore (clean .err files on each restart of Netbeans).

I even did a shortcut of this bat file with the Netbeans icon to have something like the original exe (you can put it in your task-bar for exemple).

[Capture of the bat file + shortcut to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR2qv.png)

You can find a zip containing my bat and my shortcut in the link bellow, just modify it to your liking.
https://www.mediafire.com/?svnl89vybdhczld

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, clear the userdir(.netbeans/8.0.2) and the cache(.cache/netbeans/8.0.2) directories completely and launch Netbeans again. This will remove the incorrect error badges.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was not `userdir` that makes the error, it was `cachedir`.

> The cachedir is separate from userdir and its default path is also system specific:

- C:\Users\\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\ on Windows
- /Users//Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/ on Mac OS X
- /home//.cache/netbeans/8.2 on Unix-like systems

I try to find the root cause by finding .err and .warn using `find` command.

- find . -name *.err -type f
- find . -name *.warn -type f

I find 0 warn file and 4 error files. However, the error files is not related to my project.

I ended up deleting (or rename to .old) Caches/NetBeans/8.2/, I open up NetBeans and the error icon is gone. Beware that using this approach NetBeans will take a longer time to launch.

Answer (score 0):

On netbeans 11 it was not enough to just remove the .err and .warn files. I had to remove the index directory which was in ~/.cache/netbeans/11.0