# How do you flush Netbeans synatx error information?

Tags: caching, netbeans

**Opps:** This is the same as: [Is there a way to reset the error badges in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421932/is-there-a-way-to-reset-the-error-badges-in-netbeans) but I don't know how to mark it as such ...

My version of NetBeans 6.9.1 is currently showing a large number of syntax errors in many files, in many projects.

But, if I look at the errors, they are invalid. For example, one error says that an import is referencing a non-existent file. However, that file exists and has no syntax errors.

More importantly, despite all of the errors, the code compiles cleanly and runs correctly.

My guess is that NetBeans is caching some data (OSGi?) that is out of date or has been corrupted. This has happened before, but in the past it wasn't this bad and it magically cleared itself.

I've tried starting and stopping NetBeans, but that doesn't do it. If, as in the above case, I use NetBeans to resave the imported file, it goes away after a minute, but for large projects this is very time-consuming. (Note that I am using jVi, and saving with that embedded editor doesn't not fix the problem, it has to be the NetBeans save command).

I'd really like to find a simple way just to force the whole internal state to refresh itself. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to reset the error badges in Netbeans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421932/is-there-a-way-to-reset-the-error-badges-in-netbeans)

Answer (score 0):

To clear this error you need to shut netbeans, go to the .netbeans folder in your home directory  C:\users\.netbeans for Win 7, 
in there you will see a folder for the version you are using.
in there is a folder called var
delete this folder then re-run netbeans.

This clears the cache in Netbeans allowing it to re scan the folders correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful plugin you can use called [Cache Eraser](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40014/cache-eraser).