# Netbeans 6.8 shows errors in files, but NB 7.1 does not

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans6.8

I have a problem with a project using netbeans 6.8 shows me errors in the IDE, but compiles correctly. Using Netbeans 7.1 does not show errors and also compiles. I already checked the libraries and jar's files.

[image: Example file]

[image: Project Libaries]

[image: EJB libraries]

[image: WAR Libraries]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3546418/44522 if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common bug in Netbeans. You need to delete the .netbeans/version/var/cache/index folder in your user directory.

Each version of Netbeans has it's own cache so that's why it works in 7 and is broken en 6.8.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give clarity into what kind of application you are creating? For e.g. Is it a Struts project etc?

Say for example you are creating a Struts Project in NetBeans. You might come across a problem if the Netbeans Struts Library you used in one version of NetBeans is different from the version you are using in the second.

To resolve the issue:
Remove the Library from the project and add your own Struts JAR file.