# How to disable NetBeans error badges?

Tags: netbeans

Recently I added some third-party library to my project. NetBeans detect errors in it (like invalid json files and html in test directory...) and constantly show annoying red badges all around directory tree. I browsed whole options window and I found nothing.

[image]

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to solve the problem this way, but you can look for some `.err` files and delete them.

They are in the NetBeans directory. The path is dependent on the operating system, but you have to look for an `index` directory in NetBeans.

Comment: I cannot find any `.err` files and `index` directory in neither NetBeans nor my project directory. Mind I only use NetBeans for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the .err files in the index subdirectory of the netbeans user directory? Please see 
[Is there a way to reset the error badges in Netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421932/is-there-a-way-to-reset-the-error-badges-in-netbeans?rq=1) for more details.

Comment: Like I wrote in comment to previous answer: I have no `.err` files anywhere. Beside that, my errors are properly showed. I just want to ignore actual errors.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps to get rid of those red error icons (looks a little bit strange, but just checked and it works with NetBeans IDE 8.0 PHP Bundle):

1. Close NetBeans
2. Search `userdir` for files that have `.err` extension like that: `*.err`
3. Delete all those `.err` files
4. Start NetBeans and there should be no red error icons now

**userdir**

[FaqWhatIsUserdir](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir)

userdir locations can be:

- `userdir (usually at C:\Users\<username>\AppData\ on Windows
  7`
- `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>`
- if you've got `NetBeans Portable` just search the directory where you
  have unpacked NetBeans

The `.err` file path looks something like this:

`C:\.....\NetBeans\Cache\8.0\index\s10\errors\1\views\scripts\tinymce\plugins\wordcount\editor_plugin.js.err`